# How to give data to NN models that are being concatenated?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, conv-neural-network

I have two types of data - table dataset with labels and image set.
I am building a regression model and a CNN model that will be concatenated. The idea is that by training the CNN I will extract more features and this will help the regression model.
But I have never built such a model and I don't know how to give it the data in the model.fit section. I have two pairs of data:

- train_x, train_y from the table dataset, and
- img_train_x from the image dataset (i have test data too of course).
  So, model.fit accepts only two vars - X, y. I don't know where to place the data from the images.

Here is my model:

```
inputs1 = Input(shape = (1,52,53))
model1 = Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size=5, padding = 'same', activation='relu')(inputs)
model1 = BatchNormalization()(model1)
model1 = MaxPool2D(pool_size = (2,2), data_format='channels_first')(model1)

model1 = Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size=5, padding = 'same', activation='relu')(inputs)
model1 = BatchNormalization()(model1)
model1 = MaxPool2D(pool_size = (2,2), data_format='channels_first')(model1)

model1 = Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size=5, padding = 'same', activation='relu')(inputs)
model1 = BatchNormalization()(model1)
model1 = MaxPool2D(pool_size = (2,2), data_format='channels_first')(model1)

model1 = Conv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size=5, padding = 'same', activation='relu')(inputs)
model1 = BatchNormalization()(model1)
model1 = MaxPool2D(pool_size = (2,2), data_format='channels_first')(model1)

flatten = Flatten()(model1)

inputs2 = Input(shape = (1404,))
model2 = Dense(1404, activation='relu')(inputs2)
model2 = Dropout(0.25)(model2)
model2 = Dense(702, activation = 'relu')(model2)
model2 = Dropout(0.25)(model2)
model2 = Dense(702, activation = 'relu')(model2)
model2 = Dropout(0.25)(model2)
model2 = Dense(351, activation = 'relu')(model2)

concat = Concatenate()([flatten, model2])

outputs = Dense(num_regr_outputs)(concat)
```

I would appreciate the help here.

Comment: what is the shape of your initial images ? (1, 52, 53)... black and white images with channel first?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem (although new problems arose...)
I just add

```
combined_model = Model(inputs = [inputs1, inputs2], outputs = outputs)
```

in the end. This way I can add both datasets. Now the new problem is with shape, but this is for another question.